# RadioButtons have an event attached only in first table in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I've been searching a solution in this problem for several days and so far no luck.

I have three Tables filled dinamically using java servlets with DataTables contained in two Bootstrap Modal, where I have Radio Buttons to enable or disable the rows to edit/delete using Jquery and javascript but for some reason only the radiobuttons in the first page have the event and the others who are in different pages does nothing.

this is my jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:include page="/RetreiveAlumno" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Consulta de alumnos</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/prueba.css">
</head>
<body>

    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf" %>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Consulta de alumnos</h1>
            <p></p>
            <form name="alumno" id="alumno" method="GET" action="RetreiveAlumno">
                <input type="submit" value="refrescar" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <table class="table table-condensed display" id="TablaAlumno">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Nombre</b></td>
                            <td><b>Apellido paterno</b></td>
                            <td><b>Apellido materno</b></td>
                            <td><b>Carrera</b></td>
                            <td><b>Genero</b></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/tabla.jspf" %>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <table class="table table-condensed" id="TablaAlumno">
                    <tr><td><b>Opciones</b></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-lang" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Editar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Editar
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-lang" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Eliminar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Eliminar
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/ModalMod.jspf" %>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/ModalEli.jspf" %>

    <div class="loader">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/consultascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Header.jspf

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Front-End (Servlet)</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="registro.jsp">Registro</a></li>
            <li><a href="consulta.jsp">Consulta</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

tabla.jspf

```
<%-- any content can be specified here e.g.: --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${alumnos}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>${item.nombre}</td>
        <td>${item.ap_pat}</td>
        <td>${item.ap_mat}</td>
        <td>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 1}">
                    <p>SISTEMAS COMPUTACIONALES</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 2}">
                    <p>QUIMICA</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 3}">
                    <p>MECATRONICA</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 4}">
                    <p>ELECTRONICA</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 5}">
                    <p>ELECTROMECANICA</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 6}">
                    <p>INDUSTRIAL</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 7}">
                    <p>LOGISTICA</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 8}">
                    <p>GESTION EMPRESARIAL</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 9}">
                    <p>TICS</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 10}">
                    <p>MAESTRIA EN CIENCIAS DE LA INGENIERIA</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 11}">
                    <p>MAESTRIA EN CIENCIAS DE LA INGENIERIA AMBIENTAL</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item.carrera == 12}">
                    <p>DOCTORADO EN CIENCIAS AMBIENTALES</p>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:if test="${item.genero}">
                <p>Hombre</p>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${!item.genero}">
                <p>Mujer</p>
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

modalmod.jspf

```
<%-- any content can be specified here e.g.: --%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<div id="Editar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>¿Cuál es la tabla a modificar?</p>
            <form id="alu">
                <table id="TablaEdit" class="table table-condensed display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Opcion</b></td>
                            <td><b>Nombre</b></td>
                            <td><b>Apellido Paterno</b></td>
                            <td><b>Apellido Materno</b></td>
                            <td><b>Carrera</b></td>
                            <td><b>Genero</b></td>
                            <td><b>Boton</b></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/tablaMod.jspf" %>

                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>  Cancelar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

modaleli.jspf

```
<%-- any content can be specified here e.g.: --%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<div id="Eliminar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>¿Cuál es la tabla a eliminar?</p>
            <form name="eliAlumno" id="eliAlumno" method="POST" action="DelAlumno">
                <table id="TablaElim" class="table table-condensed display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Opcion</b></td>
                            <td><b>Nombre</b></td>
                            <td><b>Apellido Paterno</b></td>
                            <td><b>Apellido Materno</b></td>
                            <td><b>Carrera</b></td>
                            <td><b>Genero</b></td>
                            <td><b>Boton</b></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/tablaEli.jspf" %>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>  Cancelar
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="loader">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

consultascript.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var lang = {
    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
};
$(".dep").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#TablaAlumno').DataTable({
    "language": lang
});
$('#TablaElim').DataTable({
    "language": lang
});
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function (value) {
    return $(value).val();
};

var table = $("#TablaEdit").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        {"type": "html-input", "targets": [1, 2, 3]}
    ],
    "Language": lang
});

$("#TablaEdit td input").on('change', function () {
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    $td.find('input').attr('value', this.value);
    table.cell($td).invalidate().draw();
});
$("#TablaEdit td select").on('change', function () {
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    var value = this.value;
    $td.find('option').each(function (i, o) {
        $(o).removeAttr('selected');
        if ($(o).val() === value)
            $(o).attr('selected', true);
    });
    table.cell($td).invalidate().draw();
});

$("#alumno").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[2].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(receive, 3000);

    function receive() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[2].style.display = "none";
        location.reload();
    }
});

var check = 0;
function ar() {
    $(".radioButton").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            check = parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
;

var checkDel = 0;
function arDel() {
    $(".radioButtonEli").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checkDel = parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
;

$(".radioButton").change(function () {
    $(".dep").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    ar();
    $("input[name='nombre" + check + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("input[name='ap_pat" + check + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("input[name='ap_mat" + check + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("select[name='carrera" + check + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("select[name='genero" + check + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("input[name='submit" + check + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
});

$(".radioButtonEli").change(function () {
    $(".dep").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    arDel();
    $("input[name='eli" + checkDel + ".0']").removeAttr('disabled');
});

$("#alu").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(modify, 3000);

    function modify() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = "none";
        $.ajax({
            url: "ModAlumno",
            data: $("#alu").serialize(),
            type: "POST"
        })
                .done(function (json) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "small",
                        title: "Exito",
                        message: "El alumno ha sido modificado adecuadamente."
                    });
                    location.reload();
                })
                .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "large",
                        title: "Error",
                        message: "El alumno no se modifico adecuadamente\n\
información del error: <br>" + errorThrown
                    });
                });
    }
});
$("#eliAlumno").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(del, 3000);

    function del() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[1].style.display = "none";
        $.ajax({
            url: "DelAlumno",
            data: $("#eliAlumno").serialize(),
            type: "POST"
        })
                .done(function (json) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "small",
                        title: "Exito",
                        message: "El alumno ha sido eliminado adecuadamente."
                    });
                    location.reload();
                })
                .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "large",
                        title: "Error",
                        message: "El alumno no se eliminó adecuadamente\n\
información del error: <br>" + errorThrown
                    });
                });
    }
});
});
```

EDIT: It seems for every page there's another group of RadioButtons that is independient of others pages but without the event

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things, what's happening is that your events are not bound to the dynamic elements. You need to bind yoru events to an element that's always present. Try binding your events like this:

```
$(document).on('event','.radiobuttonclass', function(e){
   //code for event here.
});
```